# How to concatenate a long var to a url string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a number in a var from an html form, and I need to concatenate it to a create a url to refer another object.

this is my script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Change src value of iframe dynamically</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function newSrc() {
      var newSrc = document.getElementById("MySelection").elements.value;
      document.getElementById("MyFrame").src=<iframe width="100%" height="100%"  src="mstrWeb?evt=2048001&src=mstrWeb.2048001&documentID=99F70B7440539025344C83849D7B47CD&visMode=0&port=0&share=1&hiddensections=path,dockTop,dockLeft,footer&elementsPromptAnswers=9B5FD9D44FFEB1F048E58D8F48E0912E;9B5FD9D44FFEB1F048E58D8F48E0912E:+Long.toString(newSrc)"></iframe>;
     }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      select {clear:both;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <form id="MySelection">
    <form action="action_page.php">
    Username:
    <br>
    <input type="Long" name="username">
    <br>
    </form>
    <button onClick="newSrc();">Search</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

thanks in advance,
Lian

Comment: first you'd have to fix your JS, because right now your syntax errors are killing the entire script block: `... .src=<iframe`?

Comment: There's no iframe in your html.  Why are you setting the src in the script to the entire html of a frame?

Comment: you'll need to create a <iframe> element in the script before you set the src

Comment: the iframe in "MyFrame", it's another separete object in the page.

Comment: I actually have no experience in JS so please correct my errors if you can :)

Comment: the iframe object is not in the script but it does respond when I change the src in this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
document.getElementById("MyFrame").src="mstrWeb?evt=2048001&src=mstrWeb.2048001&documentID=99F70B7440539025344C83849D7B47CD&visMode=0&port=0&share=1&hiddensections=path,dockTop,dockLeft,footer&elementsPromptAnswers=9B5FD9D44FFEB1F048E58D8F48E0912E;9B5FD9D44FFEB1F048E58D8F48E0912E:" + Long.toString(newSrc);
```